# Why is my WebView not working on release?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have my Webview working on the emulator but when I release my app  it doesn't work and give me this error message :

Webpage not available

The webpage at http://www.google.com/ could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Use https or see my answer here on how to uses attributes to add the correct permissions :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832

Comment: I added a Xamarin.Android centric answer to that SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832